# Add Panorama Item to Panorama Page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

By default when you setup a panorama page on windows phone it gives me 2 pages "item one" and "item two" and I can scroll between these pages. But when I try and manually add another page (item 3) it doesn't scroll through a 3rd page instead it just sits on top of item1 and I cannot move it at all.

this is what the Visual studio template gives you:

```
        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Is it possible to have over 2 panorama pages through XAML?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pages here you mean PanoramaItems, Yes you can have multiple PanoramaItems.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Panorama Title="my application">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item3">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item4">
            <Grid/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Also read this [Panorama Design Guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202912(v=vs.105).aspx) for more details

Comment: thanks! that worked. I forgot to close the panorama item